# Regex.Split() How to only get one item into an array when only one exists?

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, list, split

It may seem a little unusual but it is quite likely that only one item is needed from a user input box. To determine the difference between the strings entered to create a working function I am using regex.split on the ;

```
string[] customlister = Regex.Split(Regex.Replace(exttypes, @"s", ""), ";");
foreach(string c in customlister){
  lister.Add(c);
}
```

exttypes is for extensions for files, example:

.exe; .bat; .css

all seperated out with a semi colon.

The problem occurs that the lister list does not gain any information if there is only one item in the list even if it ends with a semi colon.

Is there something obvious I have missed?

Answer:
added \s instead of s in the regex.replace()

added

```
exttypes = Settings.Default.customext;
```

Comment: Why the string.Split() and string.Trim() doesn't work for you?

Comment: I needed to remove all whitespace characters for the end result to work so thats why I used regex.replace, as for split, I chose to use a uniform method, do you think that would benefit from string.split more so than regex.split?

Comment: can't you use `exttypes.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the regex pattern in your `Regex.Replace(exttypes, @"s", "")` call should be `@"\s"`, not `@"s"`. The former will remove whitespace; the latter will remove all `'s'` characters, transforming (for example) your `".css"` extension to `".c"`.

From the MSDN documentation on [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx):

> If *pattern* is not found in the *input* string, the return value contains one element whose value is the original *input* string.

Thus, the error probably lies in the way you’re supplying the input or interpreting the result. The `Split` call is correct.